# Forgot iCloud password

Tags: icloud, email, password, mobileme

I forgot my password for my icloud account. When I try to recover it form iforgot.apple.com it gives me 2 options:

1- Send an e-mail to my recover e-mail address.
2- Answer the security questions

The problem is:

2- Doesn't accept my birthday (I think I made a mistake while registering)
1- It says that the e-mail will be sent to my old me.com account, which doesn't exist anymore and redirects to icloud (because of iCloud update).

Please help me. Is there any other possibility except calling apple-support.

Comment: After the iCloud update the mail was not changed to @icloud.com, it was added, as in my mail xyz@me.com will also receive emails when sent to xyz@icloud.com. Try to send the reset request to the old email, it might work.

Comment: Calling Apple Support is a rather easy procedure, nothing to be worried about.

Comment: @killswitch yes you are right, but I can't reach my iCoud account.

Comment: @killswitch and me.com redirects to icloud

Answer (score -1):

Get a new Apple ID,go to: Settings ICloud and then tap your Apple ID and then tap Sign Out then enter your new Apple ID

P.S. U can't use same Apple ID from the one that u don't remember password from.

Comment: I need to sign in with my own apple id. But I can't recover it's password.

Comment: Exactly, @SvenDallon -- apple weirdness.